# Console for Sublime Text 2

Tags: c#, sublimetext2

I'm a beginner in C# and trying to use Sublime Text for my editor.
But the default console doesn't seem to support "Console.ReadLine();"
I can't find anywhere that I can type my input with.

I searched some plug-ins, and found this REPL and CSharpreter.
However, REPL doesn't seem to support C#

[image]

and even when I try to load other languages, error message like this pops up.

[image]

What can be a good solution? Please help!

Comment: For your REPL, the "ScriptCS" option is, I suspect, the C# option you need. Unfortunately I can't read the text of your error message in the second picture, so I can't comment on that. As for a good solution: is there a reason you're not using Visual Studio Express?

Comment: Why can't you use Visual Studio? It's the best IDE I've ever used. I use Sublime for most other code, but for C# there's nothing better than the Visual Studio IDE...

Comment: @JamesCrawshaw I just wanted to conveniently use sublime text on my mac OS X as well as on Windows. My most of the work recently is confined to console application projects so i thought using sublime text would be easier and lighter

Comment: @DanPuzey the error message that i got when i clicked on, for example, "ScriptCS" was like this "WindowsError(\xc1\xf6\xc1\xa4\xb5\xc8 \xb8\xf0\xb5\xe2\xc0\xbb \xc3\xa3\xc0\xbb \xbc\xf6 \xbe\xf8\xbd\xc0\xb4\xcf\xb4\xd9)"

Comment: MS Visual Studio is also installed on my computer but I prefer the simple screen that sublime text provides.. so isn't there anyway that I can use sublime text for my c# editor?

Comment: @CharlieKo Yeah, sure you can use it as a text editor, but it'll mess your workflow up, having to switch back to visual studio to compile / debug etc. The console in Sublime isn't like the terminal/command prompt, so you probably won't be able to use it as such. You could probably set up a build system in sublime to compile C#, but that's gonna be a bit of a ball ache. You can still use sublime to edit on your mac, but I don't think you can compile on it. Mono Develop might help you there. I know it works for Linux, so there might be an OSX version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for a combination of scriptcs, scriptcs-sublime and SublimeREPL. They will let you write and execute C# code inside Sublime Text easily.

Steps to install:

1. Install [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) (like apt-get for Windows) by running the following PowerShell command:

   > @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object
   >   net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"
   >   && SET PATH=%PATH%;%systemdrive%\chocolatey\bin
2. Install scriptcs by running the following command in your CLI

   > cinst scriptcs
3. Install [Sublime Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/) (if you don't have it already). You can find the installation guide [here](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation).
4. Go to `Menu > Tools > Command Palette` and type `Install Package`, then find and install

   1. `scriptcs`
   2. `SublimeREPL`
5. Restart Sublime
6. Go to `Menu > Tools > Command Palette` and select `SublimeREPL: ScriptCS`.

You should now be running the scriptcs REPL inside Sublime Text :)

[image: scriptcs REPL in Sublime]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to develop C# code, [MS Visual Studio](http://www.visualstudio.com/) is best way to do it.

It has also express edition which is free.

Comment: okay thank you guys anyway. i'll just use visual studio instead :) i just wasted 4 hours to make it on the sublime text...lol

Comment: :) No need to implement it.