# csharp on sublime not working properly

Tags: c#, sublimetext3

I'm trying to run `Console.ReadLine()` of CSharp on `Sublime 3` but it's not working properly. Here's the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
class randomApp {
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
       Console.Write("Please enter your name:");
       string name = Console.ReadLine();
       Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name);
    }
 }
```

You see the it outputs as

> Please enter your name:

but the problem is when I tried to enter my name and hit ENTER KEY it doesn't outputs the last line which would be

> Hello some-name

I've tried it on terminal and it works properly. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, sublime 3, and the package [compile and run](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/C%23%20Compile%20%26%20Run). How can I make it work?

Comment: Please help me format my question. thanks

Comment: thanks for the edits @valentin

Comment: You need a Console.ReadLine() at the end

Answer (score 1):

You can add `ReadKey()` to hold the screen. `ReadLine()` expects a `ENTER` to be pressed, so `ReadKey()` would be better.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Please enter your name:");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: @johnpaulcavlo Can you check whether [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083091/console-for-sublime-text-2) is helpful?

Comment: oh my. I think i need to stick with the terminal then

Comment: No issues mate :) that's wiser I guess ;)

Comment: yep thanks a lot. I hope sublime will fix this soon either ubuntu, windows or etc..thanks for all the information mate. @SamGhatak.

Comment: please mark the answer if it helped - so it helps future visitors as well ;). thx

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the mark button. where is it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the end of the code, the program will stop.
Add something like `Console.ReadLine();` so your program will wait for a input.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Please enter your name:");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Just tried it and it doesn't work. The program is already running using terminal. I think the problem is in the sublime 3.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you are using Linux and the extension "Compile & Run" does not support it.

While testing your code on Windows it works exactly as expected. There is no need for using the `Console.ReadLine()` or any other kind of interrupt as other people are suggesting.

The ReadMe.md file available at https://github.com/chrokh/csharp-build-singlefile-sublime-text-2 for Compile & Run states that it is only for Windows and OSX.

It is very likely that the extension is expecting Windows/OSX end of line(EOL) character while in the program it is only recieving the Unix EOL character therefore not terminating the line and returning control to the program.

Comment: @johnpaulcalvo as long as you have mono installed, there's absolutely no reason why the plugin wouldn't work on Linux. It's already working on the command line, so you just need to tweak the `.sublime-build` file for success. What command do you use on the command line to compile and run?